# when texture painting parts of the model are stretching

Tags: texturing

[image][image]

so when making a sky island I found that my textures have been stretching I know it does not have to do with the UV because I tried to fix that and nothing happened. I also changed my texture mapping to 3d and all the other options and there was still stretching. thx for the help ahead of time.

Comment: May I see your shader nodes?

Comment: I added it I think that want you want right?

Comment: Ah yes I see, try pluggin UV from the texture coordinate node instead of object.

Comment: did it and the answer is still nope also I'm painting in the 3d view if that gives more context

Comment: Hmmm.. if you don't mind could you pack your textures into the file and then upload it so I can take a closer look?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lQwksZpB3Q2Va7oTwXRM5a3-8uJe0PXf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh sorry I meant pack them into the blend file, under file>external data>pack all into blend

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMCBeb-rhg_onSXGCqSWqSxaJ9XZa2wg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry about that i hope this is what you want

Comment: How strange, I don't actually see any stretching of the texture in the file you sent, also it doesn't have any mapping nodes or anything in the shader besides just an image texture.

Comment: anyways I will just use the 2d texture paint area to fix the mess sorry for the inconvenience.